# Using d3 to map geojson distribution data with projections

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, data-visualization, geojson

I'm trying to map bird distributions using d3. So far, I've successfully used d3 to plot and project a path of a map of Illinois. Now, I'm requesting data from the eBird api, then manipulating it to be read as geojson, then create a series of d3 circles to plot them against the map. The circles are getting created and attached to the DOM, but the projection I've defined seems to plot them too far up and to the right.

Still learning the basics of d3, so please bear with me. My code can be found in the gist below.

https://gist.github.com/cqlanus/599a6b02e5168a051fef948ba541e296

Alternatively, if I try to plot the data as a path, the path elements are created, but they don't appear on the DOM:

```
const sightings = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'sightings')

    sightings.selectAll('path')
      .data(sightingGeoArr)
      .enter().append('path')
      .attr('fill', '#000')
      .attr('d', geoPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Geojson uses an x,y format for coordinates. Your geojson however is y,x:

```
    "coordinates": [result.lat, result.lng]
```

Try:

```
    "coordinates": [result.lng, result.lat]
```

I don't have your state geojson for bounding, but I've estimated a suitable projection for the below snippet which shows your script working (I love Ebird data but I hadn't though about converting it to geojson for use in d3 before, I'll have to give it a go).

```js
const height = 500, width = 500

/* Create a color function */

/* Define a projection function */
const albersProj = d3.geoAlbers()
  .center([0,40.08])
  .rotate([88.0,0])
  .translate([width/2,height/2])
  .scale(4000)

/* Define a path function */
const geoPath = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(albersProj)
  .pointRadius(5)

/* Attach svg to page */
var svg = d3.select( "body" )
  .append( "svg" )
  .attr( "width", width )
  .attr( "height", height );

/* Attach group to svg */
var g = svg.append( "g" );


/* Get iNaturalist data */
d3.json('http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region_spp/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-IL&sci=Setophaga%20coronata&back=15&maxResults=500&locale=en_US&fmt=json&includeProvisional=true')
  .get((err, data) => {
    console.log(data.length)

    /* Manipulate it to be read as geojson */
    const sightingGeoArr = data.map(result => ({
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [result.lng, result.lat]
      }
    }))

    const sightings = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'sightings')

    sightings.selectAll('circle')
      .data(sightingGeoArr)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('fill', '#000')
      .attr('cx', d => albersProj(d.geometry.coordinates)[0])
      .attr('cy', d => albersProj(d.geometry.coordinates)[1])
      .attr('r', 2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aha - yes! Thank you - makes total sense and it works! I hadn't considered that I was flipping lat,lng coordinates.

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear